# Does the socket automatically closed after the function finishes

Tags: c, sockets

If i had a function that opens a socket and do something with it after the function finishes the socket will be closed? Known that after the function finishes all variables will be destroyed

Comment: No - returning from the function will not close files, sockets or handlers even if local variables keeping some data will go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

In C the variables aren't "destroyed", they just fall out of scope and effectively cease to exist. This isn't C++, there are no destructors, [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) isn't a thing that happens automatically.

If you open something, you are responsible for closing it, just as if you allocate memory, you're responsible for freeing it.

*Any* allocation of any kind comes with responsibility.